# How to require for the second time

Tags: ruby, load, require

Is there a way to force `require`-ing of a file for the second time?

I am writing a library that is located in a path for Ruby. I am editing the file while doing a simple test of it in IRB.

Each time I make a change to the file, I want to reload it without ending the IRB session. Using `load` requires typing the whole path to the file each time, and restarting IRB each time requires me to type all the other variable settings required for the simple test.

I just want something like `require` but that allows loading for the second time. Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Is `IRB` your only option? Can you use `pry`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`load` does not require (hmm) a full path. It expects a complete filename with an extension.

```
p load 'date.rb' #=> true
p load 'date.rb' #=> true
p load 'date'    #=> LoadError
```

Comment: I knew about the difference between whether or not having ".rb", but somehow I didn't realize about the path.

Answer (score 4):

```
:000> path = "extremely/long/path/to/my/file"
:001> load path
:002> load path
```

Answer (score 4):

You could write your own and put it in your .irbrc:

**New Hotness**

```
module Kernel
  def reload(lib)
    if old = $LOADED_FEATURES.find{|path| path=~/#{Regexp.escape lib}(\.rb)?\z/ }
      load old
    else
      require lib
    end
  end
end
```

**Minutes-Old and Therefore Busted**

```
module Kernel
  # Untested
  def reload(lib)
    if File.exist?(lib)
      load lib
    else
      lib = "#{lib}.rb" unless File.extname(lib)=='.rb'
      $:.each do |dir|
        path = File.join(dir,lib)
        return load(path) if File.exist?(path)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*For the old-and-busted version you would have to make it more robust if you wanted to support RubyGems.*

One problem with either of these solutions is that while it will force-reload the file in question, if *that* file in turn calls `require` on others (as is usually the case with gems) those files will not be reloaded.

Working around this would be really ugly. Like, maybe manually reaching into the `$LOADED_FEATURES` array and ripping out all the paths that looked to be related to the gem's name. *shudder*

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a simpler version taking advantage of existing require magic.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually, my question may have been stupid. As steenslag answers, I might not have to have worried about the path after all. But your code will be useful.